# Не видит CUPS порт 631 в Docker при билде docker образа. Как исправить?

Tags: java, docker, cups

Есть приложение, которое при запуске тестов должно выводить принтеры:

```
@Test
public void PrintServiceHandlerTest() {
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:32909/printService?version=1.0.0&operation=getDeviceList";
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), "");

    Request request = createRequest(url, requestBody);
    System.out.println(getResponseString(request));
}
```

часть кода которая возвращает принтеры:

```
        CupsClient client = new CupsClient("localhost", cupsPort);
        List<CupsPrinter> printers = client.getPrinters();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        for (CupsPrinter printer : printers) {
            JSONObject printerJson = new JSONObject();
            printerJson.put("uri", printer.getPrinterURL().toString());
            printerJson.put("name", printer.getName() + "(" + printer.getDescription() + ")");
            arr.add(printerJson);
        }
        obj.put("printers", arr);
        printOut(obj);
```

При maven сборке тесты выполняются нормально и выдает :

```
{"printers":[{"name":"CITIZEN_CT_S310II(CITIZEN CT-S310II)","uri":"http:\/\/localhost:631\/printers\/CITIZEN_CT_S310II"},{"name":"CITIZEN_CT_S310II_linux(CITIZEN CT-S310II)","uri":"http:\/\/localhost:631\/printers\/CITIZEN_CT_S310II_linux"},{"name":"PDF(PDF)","uri":"http:\/\/localhost:631\/printers\/PDF"}]}
```

но при билде образа (`docker build -t ervices .`) выдает ошибку в тестах:

```
java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:220)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:139)
    at de.spqrinfo.cups4j.operations.IppOperation.sendRequest(IppOperation.java:202)
    at de.spqrinfo.cups4j.operations.IppOperation.sendRequest(IppOperation.java:132)
    at de.spqrinfo.cups4j.operations.IppOperation.request(IppOperation.java:67)
    at de.spqrinfo.cups4j.operations.cups.CupsGetPrintersOperation.getPrinters(CupsGetPrintersOperation.java:56)
    at de.spqrinfo.cups4j.CupsClient.getPrinters(CupsClient.java:103)
    at np.ua.awis.services.printservice_1_0_0.PrintService.<init>(AwisPrintService.java:59)
    at np.ua.awis.services.HttpServer$PrintServiceHandler.handle(HttpServer.java:259)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

    # Install maven
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y maven

    WORKDIR /services

    EXPOSE 631 632

    # Prepare by downloading dependencies
    ADD pom.xml /services/pom.xml
    RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]
    RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

    # Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar

    RUN ["mvn", "clean", "install"]
```

P.S: после создания контейнера с указанием хоста (`docker create --name services --net=host -it services`), в самом контейнере принтеры видит нормально.

Как сделать чтобы cups порт 631 был виден при билде образа и не валились тесты?